# Deserialisation not working for few fields

Tags: json, json.net

I am trying to call the following API. https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/api/docs/company/company_number/companyProfile-resource.html

I generated the Data model class using https://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/. When I call the API, few fields are not getting parsed. For example Jurisdiction.

I can see that the JSON elements are not in alphabetical order is in the JSON resource linked above. But I don't Think that would make difference.

Any clues would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible that the fields not getting parsed are the same set of fields marked "optional" in the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in their API (at least on the page you provided) jusrisdiction is spelled wrong. It should be jurisdiction and if you spelled it right in your model that would be why it won't serialize. Depending on what language you are using you can use an attribute to give your model field the misspelling so it will serialize.

```
[JsonProprty("jusrisdiction")] //wrong spelling to match API
public string jurisdiction {}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. The JSON contains Jurisdictions, however the API page contains Jusrisdiction. Good spot.